# How do I determine low-level file type?

Tags: archive

[`file`(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file), when directed at some files, says e.g. "Debian binary package (format 2.0)" for `*.deb` or "OpenDocument text" for `*.odt`. I'd like to instead have a way to determine what low-level type of archive is used: e.g. it could be *ar* for Debian packages or ZIP for OpenDocument files.

How can I determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `7z` **16.02** or later with the `l`(list) option from p7zip

Here are some example outputs:

**odt**:

```
7z l test.odt 

(..)
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 20969 bytes (21 KiB)

Listing archive: test.odt

--
Path = test.odt
Type = zip
Physical Size = 20969
(..)
```

**deb**:

```
7z l test.deb 

(..)
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 47320946 bytes (46 MiB)

Listing archive: test.deb

--
Path = test.deb
Type = Ar
Physical Size = 47320946
SubType = deb
----
Path = data.tar.xz
Size = 47310792
Modified = 2017-03-09 00:04:52
Mode = -rw-r--r--
--
Path = data.tar.xz
Type = xz
Physical Size = 47310792
Method = LZMA2:26 CRC32
Streams = 1
Blocks = 1
(..)
```

**rpm**:

```
7z l test.rpm 

(..)
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 80356 bytes (79 KiB)

Listing archive: test.rpm

--
Path = test.rpm
Type = Rpm
Physical Size = 80356
Headers Size = 7726
CPU = x86_64
Host OS = linux
Created = 2016-06-06 11:01:01
----
Path = test.cpio.gz
Size = 72630
Created = 2016-06-06 11:01:01
--
Path = test.cpio.gz
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 10
(..)
```

**tgz:**

```
7z l test.tgz

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 25617349 bytes (25 MiB)

Listing archive: test.tgz

--
Path = test.tgz
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 10
(..)
```

**non-archives:**

```
(..)
ERROR: test.sh : Can not open the file as archive
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears that p7zip version 9.20 prints "Type = Deb" for Debian packages. Not quite satisfactory really.

Comment: updated version information

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the new version now has Deb in SubType field instead of Type.